# How do I make my users comment on blog posts?

Tags: small-communities, comments

I have a blog with 100 visits per days, and I have installed a [Disqus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disqus) comment section. But after a month I have still no comments! I tried some call to action on my articles post, but it doesn't work... How can I make my users comment on my content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rule number one: *You ask specific questions*.

Not:

> I wonder what other people think about this

But:

> What do you think about this? Leave a comment

... and *Leave a comment* should be a link (anything that makes it easy to comment)

Not:

> What do you think about this?

But:

> Is X workable?
>   Should I have chosen Y?
>   What have you done to solve this?

- Preferably as the last sentence of your blog post
- Maybe also start the post with that question - you could even make it the title.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion - If you have personal relationships with any of your readers, you can always send them a note to check out your blog and *request* that they leave a compelling comment on your blog. I've found that if you're sharing meaningful content and transparent with your intentions, people are willing to lend a hand. For example:

Hi X! I just published this article that was inspired by your research on XX and I think my readers would love your additional insight! If you have a free moment, please read and comment. Thanks so much and I look forward to hearing your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by commenting your self.
Ask a couple of friends to comment and start a discussion, this might help catch the attention and reduce friction to post the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest in addition to the points raised above:

- Are you writing content that informs, or content that invites discussion?  If it's the former, then maybe people don't feel a need to comment because you've answered their question or given them the information they were seeking (maybe take a look at bounce rate, which might be high if this is the case). In that case, maybe a CTA like "if this post helped you, please leave a comment below!" might encourage them to comment.
- Use your Analytics/Search Console/[answerthepublic.com](https://answerthepublic.com) data to dig into what questions people are asking about your topics of interest, and use that to generate content around that area which proposes some ways to address those questions but leaves some areas open for discussion
- Leverage social media to open up discussions around the topics you're covering.  Research who talks about those topics and mention them when you share the post inviting comment

You could also write a post specifically asking people what they would like to know about, or have a poll on social media to generate ideas for content. Once you write the content up, you can then directly mention those people and invite them to add their thoughts.

Finally, are you leaving thoughtful, engaging comments on the blogs/articles of others?  I'm often much more likely to leave a comment on someone's articles if they are an active responder to my own content. It's worth a thought - do as you would like others to do!